# Rails 4: stop `rake` from running all rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

A developer had authority to drop a DB but not re-create it.  While working on a `rake` tasks, he accidentally ran the entire `rake` suite, which included destroying the development DB but without the proper authority to re-create and populate it.

How can I ensure this doesn't happen again?  Is there someway in the Rails app to override running `rake` so that it does NOT execute a bunch of unspecified tasks?

The developer was looking for a list of tasks and figured that running `rake` would provide that listing, similarly to how running `rails` by itself puts out instructions.

I know there's a binstub for `rake`, but I really do not know what happens if I mess with things in there.

Are there any good solutions to a situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a note from Dave's answer and another SO question (couldn't find link again), here is how you can override the default `rake` tasks in Rails 4.

```
# lib/tasks/default.rake (name is not important)
namespace :override do
  task :default do
    puts "This is now the default rake task executed via 'rake'"
  end
end

# Remove default task and switch to above (still in same file)
task(:default).clear.enhance ["override:default"]
```

At the terminal:

```
$ rake
/lib/tasks/default.rake: this is now the default 'rake' task
```

If there is a "cleaner" or more "conventional" Rails way, anyone's welcome to shout it out.  This is the "cleanest" solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default task? IIRC, outside of a `namespace` block:

```
task :default => "something_that_doesnt_destroy_the_world"
```

Comment: So if I have `lib/tasks/default.rake`: `task default: do puts "..." end` it will get run when a execute a `rake`?

Comment: @DanL I don't know, I would have assumed it took a string namespace/task, but maybe it takes blocks too.

Comment: It sounds "good" to me but I would need to test in a new environment to verify it actually over-rides the default `rake` command.  If so I'll accept this answer!